# I can't find my SQL server's name

Tags: sql-server, ssms

SQL Server 2008 which my company uses. I have no experience with databases so I'm noob to this DB things.

I have good SQL book which wrote in Korean. I just followed tutorials in that book.

But I have problem with connecting to my database.

After googling for this problem, I find out I should use `.\SQLEXPRESS`. I don't understand why should I write `.\` first, the book says just put `SQLEXPRESS` in server name text box.

I tried `(local)` and `127.0.0.1` but everything wasn't work. If I set config right, it should work right?

Is there something wrong with my SQL Server?

If you guys had same mistake I took, please tell me what's wrong.

Sorry for broken English and thank you in advance.

Comment: `.\SQLEXPRESS` means the SQL Server instance name is `SQLEXPRESS`. the dot before slash means current local server

Comment: [Logging In to SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/logging-in-to-sql-server)

Comment: Try using a **.** (dot) for the connection string specifically for localhost and if you have a server running, then use the IP address of that machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For localhost, try something like this for the connection:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="DemoEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DemoClasses.csdl|res://*/DemoClasses.ssdl|res://*/DemoClasses.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=Demo;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Or simply this without using `EF`:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="DemoEntities" connectionString="data source=.;initial catalog=Demo;integrated security=True;providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

In the data source, just put a **.** (dot) as written above and it'll work.

**Note**: Put the database name in the initial catalog section.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a program called SQL Configuration Manager, in it you can find the name of all instances of SQL you have on this machine, do you know the version of SQL you are running? /SQLEXPRESS is for express versions, maybe it is /SQLSERVER or it is not a named instance at all, meaning you should use just the IP Address